# Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName work on windows 7 and not on XP

Tags: c#, networking, windows-7, windows-xp

I am developing a tool to scan local network in c# and found that `Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName` does the job : it triggers an exception when the IP is unused. It works fine on windows 7 but on windows XP valid ip also triggers an exception.

Do you understand why I experience this behavior ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Use the [network browser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using), don't randomly connect to all IP addresses in your subnet.

Comment: What is the exception? Please post the message verbatim.

Comment: Thank you CodeCast I will try with your idea

Comment: Yes the exceptions triggered on 7 and XP are not the same. On 7 I get "socketexception :unknown host", that's what I wanted and on XP i get "socketexception : The requested name is valid and has been found in the database, but it doesn't have associated data sought". The error messages were in french, i translated so sorry if it's not accurate.

Comment: have you testing with an Xp with minimum Service Pack 2?
in [IphHostEntry class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.iphostentry.aspx) it's required.